# How to get type of each parameter for generic method

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to get the type information of the parameters of a function passed into the constructor.

```
export class Test<T> {
  constructor(
     test: ((... params : any[]) => T) | (( ... params : any[] ) => Promise<T>
  ) {
     // Convert function or promise to promise
     this.test = this.test = (...params: any[]) => Promise.resolve(test(...params))
  }

  // How I store the promisify'd function/promise
  private test : (...params) => Promise<T>

  // I want to see typing information on the parameters for this method
  public async execute(...params: any[]) : Promise<any> {
     try {
        return await this.test(...params)
     } catch (error) {
        return error
     }
  }
```

When a function or promise is passed in, I store it as a promise. Currently the typing information is lost.

In the execute method, I'd like to be able to see the typing information on the parameters to be passed in; they should match the original functions' parameters.

For example;

```
let test = new Test( (a: number, b: string) : string => `${a}${b}`)
let output : string = test.execute(1, 'b') // should compile
let output : number = test.execute(1, 'b') // should not compile
let output : string = test.execute('b', 1) // should not compile, and this is the one I'm looking for.
```

Any ideas? I was wondering if I can use `keyof` in a clever way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typing of the variadic arguments [is proposed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), but still in discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find a better way to do it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get argument types at runtime, the type information is all erased during compilation. You could however add an extra parameter to the constructor and type it in as a Boolean literal type, so that if the function returns a promise the second parameter MUST be true  and if it returns a value the second parameter MUST be false:

```
export class Test<T> {
    constructor(test: ((... params : any[]) => T), isPromise: false)
    constructor(test: ( ... params : any[] ) => Promise<T>, isPromise: true)
    constructor(
       test: ((... params : any[]) => T) | (( ... params : any[] ) => Promise<T>),
       isPromise: boolean
    ) {
       // Convert function or promise to promise
       if(!isPromise) {
           this.test =  (...params: any[]) => Promise.resolve(test(...params))
       } else {
           this.test = test;
       }
    }
     // How I store the promisify'd function/promise
    private test : (...params: any[]) => Promise<T>
}

let test = new Test<string>((a: number, b: string) : string => `${a}${b}`, false) //ok
let test2 = new Test<string>( (a: number, b: string) : string => `${a}${b}`, true) // compiler error
let test3 = new Test<string>( (a: number, b: string)  => Promise.resolve(`${a}${b}`), true) //ok
let test4 = new Test<string>( (a: number, b: string)  => Promise.resolve(`${a}${b}`), false) // compiler error
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me a possible solution. I marked the other answer as correct but your answer is a good work-around for a different problem I was having. I was looking at the parameters for the function passed in more than the constructor of Test<T> however. Thanks again!